# Combinatoric sums

Tags: combinatorics

How to calculate these sums (independent of n):

1. $\sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^k C_n^k$
2. $\sum_{k=0}^{n/2} C_n^{2k}$
3. $\sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{C_n^k}{k+1}$

I have tried to use the formula $\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$ but I couldn't figure anything except that in the first one I'v got $0$ with some tests.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: All three are most easily shown with combinatorial arguments, though the third requires a little algebraic manipulation first. Remember that $\binom{n}k$ is the number of $k$-element subsets of $[n]=\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$. Thus, for instance, the second sum is just counting the number of subsets of $[n]$ whose cardinalities are even.

For the third, note that

$$\frac1{k+1}\binom{n}k=\frac{n!}{(k+1)!(n-k)!}=\frac1{n+1}\cdot\frac{(n+1)!}{(k+1)!(n-k)!}=\frac1{n+1}\binom{n+1}{k+1}\;,$$

use that to rewrite the sum, and **then** argue combinatorially.